# How to embed voila in slides from localhost?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, powerpoint, python-3.7, ipywidgets, voila

I have a rendered voila with just a graph but with interactive slider. Suppose this is the link :

http://localhost:8888/voila/render/Untitled2.ipynb

How can I embed this in slides so I can move the slider also in a slide, particularly in PowerPoint?

Comment: What makes you think you can? (I don't know Voila - so this is a genuine question.)

Comment: @MartinPacker ive seen web viewer add ins in powerpoint, but it can only accept https/secure website. Btw the output of link actually a kind of dashboarding website, not notebook. Maybe if there any other startegy to embed this in powerpoint, feel free ! :)